# next() doesn't play nice with any/all in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, generator-expression

I ran down a bug today that came about because I was using `next()` to extract a value, and 'not found' emits a `StopIteration`.

Normally that would halt the program, but the function using `next` was being called inside an `all()` iteration, so the `all` just terminated early and returned `True`.

Is this an expected behavior? Are there style guides that help avoid this kind of thing?

Simplified example:

```
def error(): return next(i for i in range(3) if i==10)
error() # fails with StopIteration
all(error() for i in range(2)) # returns True
```

Comment: The same thing happens in Python 3.

Comment: @khelwood thanks, I'll remove the py2.7 tag

Comment: Of course. [**all** *(iterable)* Return True if all elements of the iterable are true ***(or if the iterable is empty)***.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

Comment: `iter([])` could replace your function. Interestingly, `any(iter([]))` is False.

Comment: @tdelaney because `any` returns `True` if the iterable contains any value that is `True`. `all` returns `True` if the iterable contains NO values that are `False`.

Comment: So..., all items in the collection are truthy (because there aren't any) but no single item is truthy (because there aren't any).

Comment: `next((i for i in range(3) if i==10), None)` will return `None` instead of raising a `StopIteration` exception.

Comment: @AdamSmith - you stole my line! I should have typed faster.

Comment: @tdelaney: `any` means `at least 1`. All means `every single one`.

Comment: @tdelaney, *all items in the collection are truthy (because there aren't any)*. It doesn't work like that. The *collection* satisfies the `all()` predicate because it is empty, so no items violate the predicate. Conversely, the collection does not satisfy the `any()` predicate because it is empty, so no single item satisfies that predicate.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - um, that's what i said.

Comment: @tdelaney, um, I may have misunderstood, but you said *all items in the collection are truthy*, and I said that's not what we mean in the general case.

Comment: @FredericHamidi "all items are truthy" is *exactly equivalent to* "there are no items which are not truthy"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

While this is the default behaviour in Python versions up to and including 3.6, it's considered to be a mistake in the language, and is scheduled to change in Python 3.7 so that an exception is raised instead.

As [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/#rationale) says:

> The interaction of generators and `StopIteration` is currently somewhat surprising, and can conceal obscure bugs. An unexpected exception should not result in subtly altered behaviour, but should cause a noisy and easily-debugged traceback. Currently, `StopIteration` raised accidentally inside a generator function will be interpreted as the end of the iteration by the loop construct driving the generator.

From Python 3.5 onwards, it's possible to change the default behaviour to that scheduled for 3.7. This code:

```
# gs_exc.py

from __future__ import generator_stop

def error():
    return next(i for i in range(3) if i==10)

all(error() for i in range(2))
```

… raises the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gs_exc.py", line 8, in <genexpr>
    all(error() for i in range(2))
  File "gs_exc.py", line 6, in error
    return next(i for i in range(3) if i==10)
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gs_exc.py", line 8, in <module>
    all(error() for i in range(2))
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

In Python 3.5 and 3.6 *without* the `__future__` import, a warning is raised. For example:

```
# gs_warn.py

def error():
    return next(i for i in range(3) if i==10)

all(error() for i in range(2))
```

```
$ python3.5 -Wd gs_warn.py 
gs_warn.py:6: PendingDeprecationWarning: generator '<genexpr>' raised StopIteration
  all(error() for i in range(2))
```

```
$ python3.6 -Wd gs_warn.py 
gs_warn.py:6: DeprecationWarning: generator '<genexpr>' raised StopIteration
  all(error() for i in range(2))
```

Comment: thanks -- I had my fingers crossed being surprised by StopIteration bubbling didn't make me crazy

Comment: Does this mean that `all(some_iterator)` and `mlist = [i for i in some_iterator];all(mlist)` would behave differently?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, if `some_iterator` is a generator that raises `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 9):

The problem isn't in using `all`, it's that you have a generator expression as the parameter to `all`. The `StopIteration` gets propagated to the generator expression, which doesn't really know where it originated, so it does the usual thing and ends the iteration.

You can see this by replacing your `error` function with something that raises the error directly:

```
def error2(): raise StopIteration

>>> all(error2() for i in range(2))
True
```

The final piece of the puzzle is knowing what `all` does with an empty sequence:

```
>>> all([])
True
```

If you're going to use `next` directly, you should be prepared to catch `StopIteration` yourself.

Edit: Nice to see that the Python developers consider this a bug and are taking steps to change it in 3.7.

Comment: ok -- so you're saying the solution is to not use `any`/`all` around anything that can raise a `StopIteration`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it's caught by the generator expression itself.

Comment: OP can either catch the exception or use the default value of `next`

Comment: @amwinter it's more than that - the advice is to *not* call anything that could raise `StopIteration` from within a generator expression.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - it's a good explanation of the current state of affairs.

Comment: It was me that downvoted, but it was a total accident... I must have accidentally clicked my mouse when the cursor was on the downvote button.  I just noticed and it won't let me undo because too much time has expired.  @MarkRansom if you make an edit I can undo my accidental downvote.